# Using facts in puppetlabs iptables module

Tags: puppet

I'm want to use machine ip address inside manifest, but puppet is failing with:

> Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter destination failed on
>   Firewall[004 accept ssh]: host_to_ip failed for ${address}, exception
>   no address for ${address} at /etc/puppetlabs/

```
firewall { '004 accept ssh':
    proto => 'tcp',
    destination => '$::ipaddress',
    dport  => '22',
    action => 'accept',
  }
```

How can I obtain IP address automatically here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put a variable inside a string literal `''` so the fact variable `$::ipaddress` would not interpolate or resolve correctly. It is interpreted literally as `$::ipaddress`. You should change it to:

```
firewall { '004 accept ssh':
  proto => 'tcp',
  destination => $::ipaddress,
  dport  => '22',
  action => 'accept',
}
```

You can also interpolate it with `""`, but there is no real reason to do it that way.

Although you did the right thing and established the fact as a global variable for backwards-compatibility, you can also futureproof it if you are using `Facter >= 3` by doing:

```
firewall { '004 accept ssh':
  proto => 'tcp',
  destination => $facts['ipaddress'],
  dport  => '22',
  action => 'accept',
}
```

You can also specify it directly in the facts networking hash, but that is probably overkill.